I'm using a pinescript code for a dynamic trailing stop loss. The TSL seems to exit shortly after entering. Why?
This trailing stop loss code is suppose to be dynamic. I should use something similar to a supertrend to tighten the stop loss as it continues.
Entries an exits on chart
 This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
 ZenAndTheArtOfTrading / PineScriptMastery.com

 // @version=5
 strategy("www.PineScriptMastery.com", overlay=true)
 
 Get user input
 tradeType           = input.string(title="Trade Direction", defval="Long", options=["Long", "Short"], confirm=true)
 trailSource         = input.string(title="Trail Source", defval="Lows/Highs", options=["Lows/Highs", "Close", "Open"], confirm=true)
 trailMethod         = input.string(title="Trail Method", defval="ATR", options=["ATR", "Percent"], confirm=true)
 trailPercent        = input.float(title="Trail Percent", defval=10, minval=0.1, confirm=true)
 swingLookback       = input.int(title="Lookback", defval=7, confirm=true)
 atrPeriod           = input.int(title="ATR Period", defval=14, confirm=true)
 atrMultiplier       = input.float(title="ATR Multiplier", defval=1.0, confirm=true)
 
 MACD Calculation on 3-minute chart
 [macdLine, signalLine, _] = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "3", ta.macd(close, 12, 26, 9))
 macdHist = macdLine - signalLine
 
 Condition: MACD goes from falling to rising
 macdRising = ta.crossover(macdHist, 0)
 
 Declare trailing price variable (stores our trail stop value)
 var float trailPrice    = na
 float next_trailPrice   = na
 
 Get required trailing stop variables
 atrValue                = ta.atr(atrPeriod) * atrMultiplier
 float swingLow          = ta.lowest(low, swingLookback)
 float swingHigh         = ta.highest(high, swingLookback)
 
 Get trailing stop price
 if trailMethod == "ATR" // Determine ATR trailing stop price based on price source
 next_trailPrice := switch trailSource
         "Close"     => strategy.position_size > 0 ? close - atrValue : close + atrValue
         "Open"      => strategy.position_size > 0 ? open - atrValue : open + atrValue
 strategy.position_size > 0 ? swingLow - atrValue : swingHigh + atrValue
 else if trailMethod == "Percent" // Determine percentage trailing stop price based on price source
 float percentMulti = strategy.position_size > 0 ? (100 - trailPercent) / 100 : (100 + trailPercent) / 100
 next_trailPrice := switch trailSource
         "Close"     => close * percentMulti
         "Open"      => open * percentMulti
 strategy.position_size > 0 ? swingLow * percentMulti : swingHigh * percentMulti
 
 Check for trailing stop update
 if strategy.position_size != 0 and barstate.isconfirmed
 Trail long stop ONLY IF temp trailPrice is not set or is a higher price
 if (next_trailPrice > trailPrice or na(trailPrice)) and strategy.position_size > 0
 trailPrice := next_trailPrice
 Trigger alert
 alert(message="Trailing Stop updated for " + syminfo.tickerid + ": " + str.tostring(trailPrice, "#.#####"), freq=alert.freq_once_per_bar_close)
 Trail short stop ONLY IF temp trailPrice is not set or is a lower price
 if (next_trailPrice < trailPrice or na(trailPrice)) and strategy.position_size < 0
 trailPrice := next_trailPrice
 Trigger alert
 alert(message="Trailing Stop updated for " + syminfo.tickerid + ": " + str.tostring(trailPrice, "#.#####"), freq=alert.freq_once_per_bar_close)
 
 Draw data to chart
 plot(strategy.position_size != 0 ? trailPrice : na, color=color.red, title="Trailing Stop")
 
 Entry condition: Enter a long position if MACD goes from falling to rising and on the 3-minute chart
 if macdRising and timeframe.multiplier == 3 and timeframe.isintraday
 strategy.entry(id="Long Entry", direction=strategy.long)
 
 Exit trade if stop is hit
 strategy.exit(id="Trail Exit", from_entry="Long Entry", limit=na, stop=trailPrice)

I was expecting the trailing stop loss to continue until the conditions as I understood them were met. I tried adjusting the sensitivity of the trailing stop loss but it did not help.
